# When using geopandas explore() method is there a way to restrict the boundaries of the resulting map?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to show an interactive heatmap of the United States using explore(). But it shows the entire world. Is there any way to restrict it to only the United States?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass same parameters as if you were using **folium** directly.  For example, center on USA geometry centroid

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf.explore(
    "pop_est",
    cmap="Blues",
    location=gdf.loc[gdf["iso_a3"].eq("USA"), "geometry"]
    .apply(lambda g: [g.centroid.xy[1][0], g.centroid.xy[0][0]])
    .values[0],
    zoom_start=3,
    control_scale=True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks that does zoom in on the US upon first load. But you can still navigate to the whole world. Is it possible to make the navigation itself limited to the US?

Comment: Exactly - defining starting location

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the minimum and maximum bounds of the map and force bounce back if the user wants to go away.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
us = gdf[gdf.iso_a3 == "USA"]
bounds = us.total_bounds

us.explore(
    min_lat=bounds[1],
    min_lon=bounds[0],
    max_lat=bounds[3],
    max_lon=bounds[2],
    max_bounds=True,
)
```

Comment: thank you so much yes that does cause the desired effect of limiting the user. but this seems like a workaround, so is it correct to say then that there just is no way to prevent rendering of the entire world and only render the US? bc the other issue I was hoping to resolve with this was the fact that when saved to HTML it creates an 80 MB file which is not feasible for my use case. I thought if it only rendered the smaller area that not only would it limit the user but it would lower the size too. I tried using gdp.simplify() as a workaround for the size issue but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround, this is the part of the API and an expected way of managing it. Note that background tiles take no space in the HTML, they're dynamically loaded. So it wouldn't help. The 80 MB takes the data you're trying to show most likely. `explore` is not meant to be a solution for webmaps but for local interactive exploration. For webmaps you'd need something like vector tiles. `simplify()`, if used with a reasonable precision should help though.